# Notificacion Push en windows automatica

Tags: javascript

Buenas, quiero mandar una notificacion push en windows automática a todos los usuarios que yo elija, cada vez que alguien haga un registro en la base de datos o cada vez que alguien ejecute una funcion.

Tengo este código en js que envia una notificacion push, pero quiero que no sólo se envíe la notificación al usuario que ejecute este script, sino a todos los usuarios que yo elija.

```html
<script>
    Push.create("Aviso de prueba", {
    body: "Esto es una notificacion de aviso",
    icon: 'img/logo.jpg',
    timeout: 4000,
    onClick: function () {
        window.location="mi_url";
        this.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tienes algún websocket? Como piensas distinguir que usuario debería ejecutarla y cual no? Como le "avisas" al usuario que la ejecute?

Comment: No tengo websocket, utilizo oneSignal para enviar notificaciones, pero queria hacerlo nativo en mi webapp

Comment: Personalmente nunca utilice oneSignal, pero debería de tener un filtro de a quien enviar la notificación. El código que muestras solo crea la notificación y todos deberían tenerlo, solo que deberías avisarle a quien quieras que lo ejecute; no se si me explico.

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a enviarle un mensaje a alguien tendrías que "pedirle permiso", es decir, que se muestre una ventana donde se le pregunte al usuario si quiere recibir notificaciones.

```
var ver = document.querySelector("#ver");/*Se activa en este caso con un boton*/
ver.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(Notification.permission);
        if(Notification.permission == 'granted'){
            alert("Permiso aceptado");
        }
        else{
            alert("Permiso denegado");
        }
    })
```